# I am trying to fetch Chromium for iOS, but stuck in fetch iOS command

Tags: javascript, java, ios, swift, google-chrome

I want to use Chromium for my iOS app for that I am following the doc (https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/ios/build_instructions.md)

1- I have cloned depot_tools on may desktop 
2- then as per instruction I have created an empty directory on my desktop with name Chromium and moved to Chromium dir.

Now there is a line - Run the fetch tool from depot_tools to check out the code and its dependencies.

which I am not able to understand how to do that and how to execute fetch iOS command.

Answer (score 1):

Above the 'create directory' bit on the chromium website there's a section that requires you to 
`export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/depot_tools"`

Fill in the correct path to your deposit_tools file and run it, then run 
`fetch chromium`

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried it but didn't worked for me the problem remains same it shows "/Users/aakarshgoel/Desktop/depot_tools/fetch: line 12: exec: vpython3: not found"

Comment: Write a comment under the answer, not a new answer.